# Comparing Images - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am implementing a modelling tool in order to simulate an electromagnetic phenomenon on MATLAB. Hence, I should compare the tool's output images (Geometry and Amplitude of the pattern) to a refrence images ( got from a commercial software). 
I don't really know how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you should first define what you mean by _comparing_. For example, are we simply talking about overlaying one image over the other ?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time top read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). SO is *not* a tutorial service, and questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.

Comment: okay, What I mean by comparing : my modelling tool outputs an image of a photonic structure caracterized with an amplitude distribution and a phase. Therefore I need to define a procedure to qualify the correspondance between the Modelling tool images and the refrence images. 

In other terms I want to detect the correspondance in Amplitude and phase.

Comment: @desrtnaut Thank you for your your advice. I was not asking for a tutorial. I wanted to know how to proceed. Ideas and recommandation are welcomed.

Comment: I've done this type of "comparison".  It sound like you want to demonstrate "correctness" or fidelity by showing you get a similar result as another tool.  This is a valid comparison.  If you have a field plot with amp and phase at each point you could take the coherent difference on a log10 scale.  We do this in radar modeling all the time, using method of moments algorithms.  A relative error may cause you problems if your field plot has zeros in it.  You'd be looking for the difference to be, for example, 150dB-300dB lower than your values.

Comment: Part 2: You can work out the dB level for single and double precision errors.  What actually constitutes "acceptable" is up to you.  As for doing it in MATLAB you are taking the diff of two matrices delta_M = Mcom - Msim, and going from there.  Is your question really a MATLAB question or a sim verification & validation question?

Comment: @ggcg Thank you. Yes my question is a MATLAB question.

Comment: @Mariemjeddi, there isn't a single clear question.  "How to proceed" is very broad.  Can you narrow it down,

Comment: @ggcg: okay, I have 2 png pictures ( of a light field)  from diffrent software and I need to compare those images. Basically I need to compare the amplitude and the phaase evolution. 
https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S1386947715300771-fx1.jpg

Comment: I tried to compare the images histogramme with matlab but it's not useful in my case

Comment: No, histogram is a statistical measure.  You need to define a random variable and apply the histogram to large data sets of that random variable.  If both data sets are form some high fidelity sim you need to compare bit-wise the values.  the coherent different I described in an earlier comment would be an appropriate measure.

Comment: I am not following. the random variable concept is not clear.